# Completing the final room of Kumoon?

Tags: kumoon-classic

Ok, first, a bit about the game.  Kumoon is a small 3D game where you control a chick through various rooms of stacked blocks.  the goal is to knock all of the red blocks down by shooting them, or pushing them with other blocks.  I wouldn't be surprised if nobody else here has played this little 3D physics gem, but if you have, maybe you can help me out.

#### I cannot figure out how I'm supposed to pass the final room (room 39) of this game.  I've tried everything I can think of, but no luck.  Any ideas?

---

[image: Screenshot of the game. Looks fun, dunnit?]

Note: Even if you haven't played Kumoon before, I sincerely suggest you give it a try.  It's a tiny download, and surprisingly entertaining.  It should only take you maybe 45 minutes to get through it the first time, depending on how quickly you get the hang of it, however **make sure** you read the
[Kumoon homepage](http://mayoneez.1g.fi/kumoon/) for information about scoring, or else you'll be completely lost on how it works.

Comment: The link is outdated. This works : http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=18298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. First practice taking a position, and memorizing it relative to the target post.

There is the one post in the center, learn that, then learn one of the corner posts.

With both position and target positioning on the grid memorized, start the level clean. Find the correct angle to shoot the boxes off the center pole and the corner poles, and one-shot each box one by one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a walktrough

- [Kumoon Walktrough Level 36-39 (Part 3/3)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIu7mZzngiE)

Try it =)

Comment: This player is using an exploit, but still, I guess this should work for me.  Thanks.

Comment: The exploit was a bit boring, I'm surprised people used it so much even though most clearly understood that it was not an intended mechanic.

The new version of Kumoon has changed that a bit, but the changes have given rise to new exploits : )